# Using setters and getters between 3 classes

Tags: class, object, getter-setter

I know this is a basic question but I really struggle with this :(

First class:

```
public class A{


C c= new C();
B b= new B();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    b.start();
    System.out.println(c.getSomething());
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class B{


C c= new C();

public void start(){
   c.setSomething(2);
    }
}
```

Third Class:

```
  public class C{


int x;


  public int getSomething() {
    return x;
}
public void setSomething(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
}
```

Now I know I make a new object in class A thats why the sysout returns null.
How can I make it so that I GET the value 2 instead of null in class A, and that I'm able to SET things in class B.
So I stay at the same object so to say.

I just want to be able to SET things in class B and GET that same value from the setter-getter-class-C, in class A. Please help

Thanks in advance, Jimme